# How to set database values to react-redux state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, redux, react-redux

I am using react-redux and trying to pre-populate a form with values if it has previously been filled out. So there is an api endpoint that I am getting the pre-populated form values(currently stored in state)like this.

Just need to store the data from api I called from the componentDidMount and store it inside the redux store. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single action for set data. It will contains all the data you want to set. And in redux just put it with spread operator (like ...action.payload)

Comment: I seem to be getting the following when I try to set the firstName value for the input to this.props.firstName: [object Object]

Comment: Now you can simpify this
In each case you put data from action with the same key as it in the store
Use this
`
function reducer(state = initialState, {type, ...action}) {
  switch (type) {
case SET_KYC_INFO_FROM_DATABASE:
      return {
        ...state,
        kycForm: {
          ...state.kycForm,
          ...action
    }
`
here you will save all the data you received to action (without type) ant paste it in state.kycForm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).